# Mark fields not valid as red with knockout/durandal

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal

I am learning knockout, Durandal and Breeze and thanks to the **JumpStart SPA video from John Papa** this is a pleasure. So I examine the code of this project and right now I am trying to change the validation mechanism.

At this time, when saving changes, if the save failed, we collect the errors and display a toast with a resume of the errors.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is:

- having the ability to mark fields not valid in red (background-color) in the view
- when a toast is displayed with the validation errors resume (something like: 'Save failed: affairNr is required' ) I would like to replace the property name with a more friendly name (something like 'Save failed: affair number is required')

Here is the portion code for the validation in the datacontext.js:

```
var saveChanges = function () {
    return manager.saveChanges()
        .then(saveSucceeded)
        .fail(saveFailed);

    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
        log('Saved data successfully', saveResult, true);
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        var msg = 'Save failed: ' + getErrorMessages(error);
        logError(msg, error);
        error.message = msg;
        throw error;
    }
};

function getErrorMessages(error) {
    var msg = error.message;
    if (msg.match(/validation error/i)) {
        return getValidationMessages(error);
    }
    return msg;
}

function getValidationMessages(error) {
    try {
        //foreach entity with a validation error
        return error.entitiesWithErrors.map(function (entity) {
            // get each validation error
            return entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors().map(function (valError) {
                // return the error message from the validation
                return valError.errorMessage;
            }).join('; <br/>');
        }).join('; <br/>');
    }
    catch (e) { }
    return 'validation error';
}
```

Does someone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

To reproduce the problem: click on the left sidebar on Transports + recherche avancee + any item in the list + on the right side: clear some inputs (like Numero d'affaire as screenshot below) then click on 'Enregistrer'. Then the save button is called. There I need to check if there are invalid inputs with ko.validation.group but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: If you're trying to maintain good view/view model separation and MVVM pattern on the client-side, I think Knockout Validation that Evan references is a good choice, because it validates the view model data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some time ago, I posted a helper function that extend observable properties to add validation based on the breeze validators. Using that helper you can achieve the red color on the invalid inputs:

[Translate breeze validation messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316454/translate-breeze-validation-messages)

I can't help you with the second question, I know that you can customize the validation message but I think that with the default validators you can't set a friendly name to show on the message.

Update:

The first that I do is to create a helper module that exposes the function (updated version):

```
define([],
function () {
"use strict";
var foreignKeyInvalidValue = 0;

function addValidationRules(entity) {
    var entityType = entity.entityType,
        i,
        property,
        propertyName,
        propertyObject,
        validators,
        u,
        validator,
        nValidator;

    if (entityType) {
        for (i = 0; i < entityType.dataProperties.length; i += 1) {
            property = entityType.dataProperties[i];
            propertyName = property.name;
            propertyObject = entity[propertyName];
            validators = [];

            for (u = 0; u < property.validators.length; u += 1) {
                validator = property.validators[u];
                nValidator = {
                    propertyName: propertyName,
                    validator: function (val) {
                        var error = this.innerValidator.validate(val, { displayName: this.propertyName });
                        this.message = error ? error.errorMessage : "";
                        return error === null;
                    },
                    message: "",
                    innerValidator: validator
                };
                validators.push(nValidator);
            }
            propertyObject.extend({
                validation: validators
            });
        }

        for (i = 0; i < entityType.foreignKeyProperties.length; i += 1) {
            property = entityType.foreignKeyProperties[i];
            propertyName = property.name;
            propertyObject = entity[propertyName];

            validators = [];
            for (u = 0; u < property.validators.length; u += 1) {
                validator = property.validators[u];
                nValidator = {
                    propertyName: propertyName,
                    validator: function (val) {
                        var error = this.innerValidator.validate(val, { displayName: this.propertyName });
                        this.message = error ? error.errorMessage : "";
                        return error === null;
                    },
                    message: "",
                    innerValidator: validator
                };
                validators.push(nValidator);
            }
            propertyObject.extend({
                validation: validators
            });
            if (!property.isNullable) {
                //Bussiness Rule: 0 is not allowed for required foreign keys
                propertyObject.extend({ notEqual: foreignKeyInvalidValue });
            }
        }
    }
}

return {
    addValidationRules: addValidationRules
};
});
```

Then, I'm defining an initializer for each breeze entity type ( http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities ). Example:

```
define(['app/validatorHelper', 'knockout'],
function (vHelper, ko) {
"use strict";
var constructor = function () {
},

    initializer = function indicadorInitializer(entity) {
        vHelper.addValidationRules(entity);
    };

return {
    constructor: constructor,
    initializer: initializer
};
});
```

And finally, somewhere ( I'm doing it on an init function inside my dataservice module ), I'm registering the initializer ( http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities ) :

```
//store comes from: manager = breezeconfig.createManager(),
//    store = manager.metadataStore,
store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Palanca", domain.palanca.constructor, domain.palanca.initializer);
```

I'm doing all of this before fetching the metadata.

I hope that this would help you.

Update 2:

I've found the problem, your version of knockout validation is not the last one.

Inside the downloaded file from: http://ericmbarnard.github.com/Knockout-Validation/ the line: 349 is:

```
exports.rules[ruleName] = ruleObj;
```

Inside your file, the equivalent line ( function addAnonymousRule ) is:

```
ko.validation.rules[ruleName] = {
    validator: ruleObj.validator,
    message: ruleObj.message || 'Error'
};
```

I think that with the lastest version should work.

Update 4:

This is the code to save:

```
vmAddPalanca.prototype.saveChangesCmd = ko.asyncCommand({
    execute: function (palanca, complete) {
        var validationErrors = ko.validation.group(palanca);
        if (validationErrors().length === 0) {
            dataservice.saveChanges()
            .then(saveChangesSuccess)
            .fail(saveChangesFail)
            .fin(complete);
        } else {
            validationErrors.showAllMessages(true);
            toastr.error("Debe corregir los errores antes de poder guardar");
            complete();
        }
    },
    canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
        return !isExecuting && dataservice.hasChanges();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm busy trying to debug your code and I got an error on:  propertyObject.extend({ validation: validators }); saying error retrieving data.

Comment: Maybe some background is needed.

There is a previous post where I show how I'm using the validation helper : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662446/knockout-validation-using-breeze-utility

The basic is that I'm using an initializer for my breeze entities and inside the initializer I'm calling the function.

I'll update my answer to give you a detailed answer.

Comment: Yes, I added knockout validation. In fact, for the 1st version of your code (with indicadorInitializer) I got no error. But with the 2nd version of your code (with addValidationRules) I got the error I give above. Any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea, if you can put the code somewhere, i can give it a look.

Comment: Here is a link to download a zip containing the VS2012 solution: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgtkm5xkkoem2cb/TRANSPORTBOEK.zip Simply open the solution, run it, on the left sidebar, click 'Transports' + 'Recherche avancée' then it will gives an error. The problem is located in App/services/model.js line 64 + 90. Thanks for your help. If I comment these lines and replace with the line below then no errors.

Comment: I've found the problem, your version of knockout validation is not the last one.
See my updates answer.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much! Your help was precious. It is a pity we cannot have the translations back from the server side (attributes on the properties).

Comment: I have another question for you: based on your code which works perfectly for getting validations rules from metadata (based on breeze), now I would like to block the 'save' in my view if some elements are invalid. I try since this morning without luck. Let's say I have en object 'transport' in my viewModel which contains some properties to validate. When I click on the save button on my view I would like to check if some properties of my 'transport' object are invalid. Any idea?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a save example. "palanca" is my entity.

Comment: Yes as you suggest I try using ko.validation.group but in my solution it doesn't work and I don't know why. I'm busy on this problem since this morning :( Validation is ok on input fields ('blah blah' is required) but on the save button I am not able to check whether there are invalid inputs (by counting on the group). May I ask you again to check in my solution? Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgtkm5xkkoem2cb/TRANSPORTBOEK.zip This drives me crazy!

Comment: I updated my question to show how to reproduce the problem. Anyway, I thank you very much for what you already do for me.

Comment: Your problem is the knockout validation config. In main.js you have: grouping: { deep: true, observable: true }. You need to put deep: false. Why? Because breeze holds a reference to the entity inside the entityAspect property, that has a entityAspect property that holds a reference to the entity... In short: a recursivity problem. With that change, the line: var validationErrors = ko.validation.group(vm.transport); should work.

Comment: You are a king. Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Yuste: hello again :) I published a new post today related with a validation problem. Maybe you can take a look if you had time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719921/need-to-enter-my-view-2-times-to-have-validation-working Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ooops wrong SO link. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727888/knockout-validation-on-my-dropdown-dont-work

Comment: Hi, any chance someone could post a full example of the entity initializer part of this?  I'm a little confused on the initializer that appears to be in a separate module, and the whole domain.entity.constructor bit?  I'm fine with the concept of extending entity constructors but what's the domain bit and how is it referenced?  Thanks.