# Knockout Validation on drop down list always displaying error message

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

When binding values to a drop down list and using knockout validation, the error message seems to always display even if my knockout validation settings say `messagesOnModified: true`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
<br />
<select data-bind="value: State">
    <option value="">Select a state...</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
     var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable().extend({
        required: { message: "You must enter a name." }
    });
    self.State = ko.observable().extend({
        required: { message: "You must select a state." }
    });

    self.Errors = ko.validation.group(self);
}

ko.validation.configure({
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true
});

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), document.body);
```

And jsfiddle to show the difference between the text box and drop down list: http://jsfiddle.net/f7v4m/

The text box is displaying the correct behavior, where the error message will only display after the value has been modified.

Why is the error message displaying for the drop down list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout validation on my dropdown don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727888/knockout-validation-on-my-dropdown-dont-work)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To remove the "initlial" validation message you need to initialize your `State` property with an empty string:

```
self.State = ko.observable("").extend({
    required: { message: "You must select a state." }
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UzH9/).

You need to do this because when writing  `ko.observable()` it will be initialized with `undefined` however when knockout evaluates the `value` binding it sets `State` to the currently selected empty option value's which is an empty string.

However `undefined` is not equal to the empty string it makes your property "dirty" and it triggers the validation message because the validation plugin thinks that your property has been modified.

Comment: Doesn't work when combined with `options` and `optionsCaption` bindings. http://jsfiddle.net/7UzH9/12/

Comment: Found a solution for `optionsCaption` binding. You need to initialize observable to `undefined` like this: `ko.observable(undefined).extend({ .. });` http://jsfiddle.net/7UzH9/13/

Comment: @krzychu The above fix is when not using the options binding. Also you don't need to specify `undefined` as `undefined` is the default for observables