# Breeze.js & Knockout.js: translating breeze validation to knockout validation causes an 'Out of stack space' or 'Too much recursion'

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, knockout-validation

I have a client side model generated by Breeze/OData and I used the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635958/mark-fields-not-valid-as-red-with-knockout-durandal) to connect it to Knockout validation.

It works great for validating individual fields through the `isValid()` method. However, whenever I try to use `ko.validation.group` against a Breeze Entity (assume that the knockout validation is configured with `{deep: true}`), either calling `showAllMessages`, `length` or any other method that performs a tree traversal over the object graph, results in an infinite recursion exception at runtime (see [`knockout.validation.js@231-271`](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Src/knockout.validation.js)). Depending on the browser can be "Out of stack space" (IE) or "Too much recursion" (Firefox).

I think the root cause of the error is that the algorithm inside Knockout Validation does not keep track of the previously visited nodes. All Breeze Entities contain an `entityAspect` property and the code inside `knockout.validation` visits all the properties and all its children using depth first, but without remembering the nodes already visited. And because `entityAspect` contains a reference back to its containing entity, it results in a stack overflow.

```
validate(entity) // Initial call
    => validate(entity.entityAspect) // Validate the first property of the root
    => validate(entity.entityAspect.entity) // Validate the first property of the child, which points back to the root!
```

So after all this, the question is: **do you know any work around to avoid this behavior?**

For now, I think I'm just going to use a dirty cheap hack inside `knockout.validation` to prevent stepping into an `entityAspect` property, but I'm sure there should be a better way.

Comment: faced a similar problem yesterday. also using a dirty dirty workaround (validation group for every navigation property, since i only need two). really not happy with that, looking forward for some answers :)

Comment: I do not know an easy way around this. Circular references are common in real world entity models (e.g., Customers have Orders and those orders refer back to their parent customers).

Comment: You might consider my answer to [**this other SO question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192457/ko-validation-group-did-not-detect-my-errors-on-my-nested-observablearray/16247951#16247951) in which I suggest writing custom validations to do the hard stuff.