# ko.validation.group did not detect my errors on my nested observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal

I develop a project with Durandal/Breeze using intensive Knockout bindings.

I have a view which is using the following observable:

```
packing
  - description
  - weight
  - ...
  - isotopes
    - name
    - activity
    - ...
```

As you can see above: my `packing` observable contains an `isotopes` observableArray inside. This `packing` object is filled from breeze with a query.

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Packings')
        .where('id', '==', packingId)
        .expand('isotopes');
```

I try to set validation in place for all of this using **ko.validation**.

- The `description` property of my `packing` observable is required
- The `name` property of my `isotopes` observableArray is required

I successfully validate on description. So whenever user clear the input field binded to `description`, this one is highlighted in red. And whenever user add a new empty entity (breeze) and click on save, this one is highlighted in red.

This works thanks to this code in the save button:

```
var validationErrorsCount = ko.computed(function () {
    if (typeof packing() == 'undefined') return;
    var validationErrors = ko.validation.group(packing());
    return validationErrors().length;
})

if (validationErrorsCount() > 0) {
    logError('Validation failed, please check.', '', true);
    ko.validation.group(packing()).showAllMessages();
    return;
}
```

So far so good.

Now I need to validate the property `name` for my `isotopes` observableArray. So whenever user clear the input field binded to `name`, this one is highlighted in red. It works. But **the problem is** whenever user add a new empty entity (breeze) of type `isotope`, don't type anything for the `name` input box and click on save, this one is not highlighted in red.

When I debug and inspect values I can clearly see that:

- `ko.validation.group(packing(), {deep:false});` did not return any invalid things
- `ko.validation.group(packing().isotopes(), {deep:false});` did not return any invalid things

So it seems that ko.validation did not detect my invalid inputs.

**My question:** how to validate my nested `isotopes` observableArray when I add a new element inside?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is another SO post with the problem: [Breeze.js & Knockout.js: translating breeze validation to knockout validation causes an 'Out of stack space' or 'Too much recursion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158463/breeze-js-knockout-js-translating-breeze-validation-to-knockout-validation-ca)

Here is my 'dirty' & temporary hack (from line 4 to 9)

```
// Check errors on the packing entity
var validationErrorsCount = ko.validation.group(packing()).length;
// Check errors on the isotopes entities !! code below is a temporary hack 
ko.utils.arrayForEach(packing().isotopes(), function (isotope) {
    if (!isotope.name.isValid()) {
        validationErrorsCount = validationErrorsCount + 1;
        ko.validation.group(isotope).showAllMessages();
    }
});

if (validationErrorsCount > 0) {
    logError('Validation failed, please check.', '', true);
    ko.validation.group(packing()).showAllMessages();
    return;
}
```

Still waiting for a better way for validating my inner (nested) models.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is an easy way. At a certain degree of complexity, it's easier to move to an "ItemViewModel". An ItemViewModel is a view-oriented wrapper around an inner entity. It exposes carefully controlled properties designed for easier binding. I [described the approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180592/sorting-breeze-navigation-properties) in connection with a different problem.

I don't know if you've hit that wall.

**Another thought**: write a couple of [custom validations](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation) for this EntityType that do the hard work of inspecting the isotopes. You'll know how to do the job "right" and efficiently in your validation method; you won't be relying on KO to walk the graph or suffer its problems with circularities.

Answer (score 1):

What if you change: `ko.validation.group(packing().isotopes(), { deep:false });`

to: `ko.validation.group(packing().isotopes(), { deep:true });`

Isn't that the point of deep?

Comment: Then I get a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceed`