# Knockout Validation on Breeze.js entities

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, knockout-validation

I'm trying to get Knockout Validation running on my Breeze.js entities but not having much luck.

So currently I'm just trying to get a very basic test working to confirm the approach should work but am stumped as to why this is not even working.  Essentially I have something like the following running when the user edits one of my entities in an attempt to register knockout validation on the resulting entity from breeze:

```
dataService.getEntity(selectedRowId())
                .then(function(result) {
                    currentEntity(result.entity);
                    var ent = currentEntity();
                    ent.TestField.extend({ required: true });
                });
```

And then in the view the field is bound:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: currentEntity().TestField" />
```

But this is not working. I thought it might be because all the fields on the entity are dependantObservables, but created a test computed field and knockout validation seems to work fine on it (provided I give it a read and write method)

Can anybody suggest what I might be missing or a better way to do this sort of thing?

(PS: I'm actually attempting something like the approach from Julián Yuste here:

[knockout validation using breeze utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662446/knockout-validation-using-breeze-utility)

but not having much luck so I'm trying to take it back to some basics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a better and updated example here:

[Mark fields not valid as red with knockout/durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635958/mark-fields-not-valid-as-red-with-knockout-durandal/15639832#15639832)

Take a look and tell me if that helps.